# Matplotlib Set Default Bar for Comparison

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar graph that I want show a comparison between actual/ expected. 
For example: [Green bar/ Grey background](http://imgur.com/aEyBBkc&7enHZ8J#0)

I took this graph from someone else but basically what I want is the "default grey bar" in the background while showing the actual data in green instead of:
[Green bar/ No background](http://imgur.com/aEyBBkc&7enHZ8J#1)

What are some method I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a stacked [bar chart](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) where the top bar in the stack always has the same maximum value. I modified the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
data1  = np.array((50, 35, 30, 33, 60))
data2 = np.array((25, 32, 34, 20, 5))

# find the size of the grey bar to be plotted at the top
ymax = 100
s = np.shape(data1)
n = s[0]
top = ymax*np.ones((n,)) - data1 - data2

ind = np.arange(n) # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35 # the width of the bars

p1 = plt.bar(ind, data1, width, color='g')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, data2, width, color='y', bottom=data1)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, top, width, color ='grey', bottom=data2 + data1)

plt.show()
```

[image: stacked bar chart with grey top]